# Best way to Filter and Map the combination of an array and an object

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to map this?
I have an array of 5 stages here which is the initial stages array. However, I need to map the following newData array against these stages. `field_4` should map against `field-4`. And `field_5` should map against `field-5`. I have also attached how it should be returned. I realise this probably isn't the proper use of StackOverflow as it's more of a question, but I've been trying for a while with no luck. Any pointers in the right direction would be great.

```
const stages = [
            { key: 'field-one' },
            { key: 'field-two' },
            { key: 'field-three' },
            { key: 'field-four' },
            { key: 'field-five' },
        ]

const newData = {
                field_four: 9,
                field_five: 'D',
            }
```

// should get

```
const stages  =
            [
                { key: 'field-one' },
                { key: 'field-two' },
                { key: 'field-three' },
                { key: 'field-four', value: 'D' },
                { key: 'field-five', value: 9 },
            ];
```

Comment: "*I've been trying for ages with no luck*" Can you share your attempt(s) as a [mre], in accordance with our [ask] guidelines?

Comment: You don't need to "map against" anything. Just loop through your array, check `key` property of your item, if it matches, assign the additional properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run a simple `map` function, compare the properties. If the required property is found, then append that object with a new value

```js
const stages = [
  { key: "bank-feeds" },
  { key: "has-property" },
  { key: "other-loans" },
  { key: "industry-code" },
  { key: "time-in-business" }
];

const newData = {
  trading_time_months: 9,
  industry_code: "D"
};

const result = stages.map((stage) => {
  const { key } = stage;
  if (key === "industry-code") {
     return { ...stage, value: newData.industry_code };
  } else if (key === "time-in-business") {
     return { ...stage, value: newData.trading_time_months };
  } else {
     return stage;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Joy! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

To update your existing `stages` variable, you can use `Object.entries` on the `newData` and search in your stages for the appropriate stage. If found, assign a value.

```js
Object.entries(newData).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  const stage = stages.find((target) => target.key === key);

  if (stage) {
    stage.value = value;
  }
});
```

Or you can go the other way around, if you don't need to adjust the existing array (preferable):

```js
const newStages = stages.map((stage) => ({
  ...stage,
  ...(newData[stage.key] != null ? { value: newData[stage.key] } : {})
}));
```

and for a more readable last version (this does not clone the object inside the array):

```js
const newStages = stages.map((stage) => {
  if (newData[stage.key] != null) {
    stage.value = newData[stage.key];
  }

  return stage;
});
```